# pattern.matcher() vs pattern.matches()

Tags: java, regex

I am wondering why the results of the java regex pattern.matcher() and pattern.matches() differ when provided the same regular expression and same string

```
String str = "hello+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("I found the text " + matcher.group() + " starting at " 
        + "index " + matcher.start() + " and ending at index " + matcher.end());
}

System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("\\+", str));
```

The result of the above are:

```
I found the text + starting at index 5 and ending at index 6
false
```

I found that using an expression to match the full string works fine in case of `matches(".*\\+")`.

Answer (score 38):

`pattern.matcher(String s)` returns a `Matcher` that can *find* patterns in the String `s`. `pattern.matches(String str)` tests, if the entire String (`str`) matches the pattern.

In brief (just to remember the difference):

- `pattern.matcher` - test if the string **contains-a** pattern
- `pattern.matches` - test if the string **is-a** pattern

Comment: actually, `find()` is the difference. the Matcher itself is not - `matcher.matches()` still returns false

Comment: @Bozho, yes, I know. But because the OP is comparing a method that returns a `Matcher` instance with another method that returns a boolean and wonders why their results are not comparable, I decided to write an easy answer, knowing that I couldn't score with it on SCJP exams ;-)

Comment: You're also glossing over the fact that `Pattern.matches` is a static method.  Try to call `pattern.matches()` with no arguments (`pattern` being an instance of `Pattern`) and your code won't even compile.

Comment: This answer is misleading, `pattern.matcher` doesn't test if the string contains the pattern, it matches the entire string to the pattern, so `\w+` matched against `"hello world"` will be false, even though `"hello world"` contains a substring that matches `\w+`. The actual difference is staticness and where the compilation of the regex happens.

Answer (score 4):

`Matcher.find()` attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

`Pattern.matches(String regex, CharSequence input)` compiles the regex into a `Matcher` and returns `Matcher.matches()`.

`Matcher.matches` attempts to match the **entire** region (string) against the pattern (Regex).

So, in your case, the `Pattern.matches("\\+", str)` returns a false since `str.equals("+")` is false.

Comment: that's the behaviour I've been looking for, it does exactly what `String.matches("regex")` does, just way faster for large iterations

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadoc, see the if, and only if, **the entire region** section

```
   /**
     * Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
     *
     * <p> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
     * <tt>start</tt>, <tt>end</tt>, and <tt>group</tt> methods.  </p>
     *
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if, and only if, <b>the entire region</b> sequence
     *          matches this matcher's pattern
     */
    public boolean matches() {
        return match(from, ENDANCHOR);
    }
```

So if your String was just "+", you'd get a true result.

Comment: Well that's just embarrassing, let me try to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

matches tries to match the expression against the entire string. Meaning, it checks whether the entire string is a patern or not.
conceptually think it like this, it implicitly adds a ^ at the start and $ at the end of your pattern.

For, String str = "hello+", if you want matches() to return true, you need to have pattern like ".*\+.*"

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: I found it counter-intuitive and doesn't match other languages. I often port code between objective-c / java / swift / c# / vb.net. In all other languages which I use (as far as I remember), the shorthand syntax search for the first occurrence of pattern, never trying to match the whole string. After all, it produce the error which sometimes hard to notice.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern.matches is testing the whole String, in your case you should use:

```
 System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(".*\\+", str));
```

Meaning any string and a + symbol

Comment: What if the target string were `hello+world`?

Comment: It depends on the needs. In that case, it would be:
System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(".*\\+.*", str));

Answer (score 0):

I think your question should really be "When should I use the `Pattern.matches()` method?", and the answer is "Never."  Were you expecting it to return an array of the matched substrings, like .NET's `Matches` methods do?  That's a perfectly reasonable expectation, but no, Java has nothing like that.

If you just want to do a quick-and-dirty match, adorn the regex with `.*` at either end, and use the string's own `matches()` method:

```
System.out.println(str.matches(".*\\+.*"));
```

If you want to extract multiple matches, or access information about a match afterward, create a Matcher instance and use *its* methods, like you did in your question.  `Pattern.matches()` is nothing but a wasted opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

In this case, a matcher object instance will be returned which performs match operations on the input text by interpreting the pattern. Then we can use,`matcher.find()` to match no. of patterns from the input text.

```
(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("\\+", str))
```

Here, the matcher object will be created implicitly and a boolean will be returned which matches the whole text with the pattern. This will work as same as the `str.matches(regex)` function in String.

Answer (score 0):

The code equivalent to `java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("\\+", str)` would be:

```
Pattern.compile("\\+").matcher(str).matches();
```

method `find` will find the first occurrence of the pattern in the string.