# Using regular expressions to find + or -

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble using regular expressions.

This is what I have:

`String expr = "1+4+3-2"

Matcher m;`

```
while(Pattern.matches("[+-].*", expr))
{
    (m = Pattern.compile("[+-](.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
    expr = parseTerm(m.group(1));
    System.out.println("+: " + expr)
}
```

I'm trying to find "+" or "-" in the string above (or any other calculations with +'s and -'s such as `1+D[0]+D[5]`). When I find a + or -, I want to do the operation with the numbers on the left and the right side of the operation. So 1+4 will add to make 5. Then 5+3 will add to make 8 and finally 8-2 will subtract to end up with 6. My current code isn't going through the while loop for some reason, so I'm not able to add or subtract anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `+` is a reserved token in regular expression. Use `"[\\+-](.*)"`

Comment: @ShivamKalra: No, not in the sybol classes `[]`.

Comment: Does your expression only contains `+` or `-`? I mean what about `*`, `/`, or `brackets`? Precendence rule has to be considered here.

Comment: Yes, I take care of * and / in another function, but that function has a problem similar to this one. It won't enter the while loop.

Comment: -1. You are not clear on what you want. People will only build solution based on your example, which you didn't specify enough.

Comment: How can I make my question clearer?

Comment: @user1831442: you need to provide sample inputs, and the output that you expect from each input. I'm not even sure what you want `matcher` to return. The functionality you describe ('I'm not able to add or substract anything') is what you expect from a parser, not a simple regex match.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862917/pattern-matcher-vs-pattern-matches

Comment: Well, basically you could just ignore everything I have inside the while loop. What I'm trying to do is, if I have a simple expression such as `expr = "1+4"` then I would want to read 1 and store 1 into some temporary variable, and then since I have a "+" in my string, I enter the while loop, read the +4, and add 4 to the variable which I have stored 1 in. Once I add 1+4, in the end I want expr to store 5, then I break out of the while loop.

Comment: regex for parsing expressions...forger it..

Comment: Exactly. You are using a hammer to peel an orange. You need an expression parser. Google for it.

Answer (score 0):

You must catch only numbers:

```
 (m = Pattern.compile("[+-]([0-9]*)").matcher(expr)).find();
```

Not any symbols! (`.*`). Because in that case you catch the entire expression.

If it possible that there are other symbols in the tokens (but not + or =),
you can do it this way:

```
 (m = Pattern.compile("[+-]([^+-]*)").matcher(expr)).find();
```

Comment: I actually didn't mention this, but it doesn't always have to be +/- followed by a number. For example, I could have 1+D[0]+5

Comment: @user1831442.. Regex is not intelligent enough to find out what your expression means. It doesn't know what `D[0]` is supposed to be. You are probably using the wrong tool.

Comment: But I don't need it to figure out what `D[0]` is. All I need to do is to enter the while loop, which it won't enter.

Comment: You're changing the assignment of m, and not the condition of the while loop so that my program enters it. I've tried changing the while loop condition to `"[+-]([^+-]*)"`, too, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Of course, you're right, I just provided an example; I didn't rewrite the whole code

Answer (score 0):

References: [pattern.matcher() vs pattern.matches()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862917/pattern-matcher-vs-pattern-matches)

```
while (Pattern.compile("[\\+-]").matcher(expr).find())
{
   ....
}
```