# matching { regular expression java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions (and to java), so this is probably a simple question.
I am trying to match the character { at the end of a line. My attempts are simply this:

```
row.matches("{$")

row.matches("\{$")
```

But both just give

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
row.matches("^.*\\{$");
```

You simply need to escape the {, since it's a metacharacter. Because Java reserves a single backslash for special contexts (\n, \r, etc.), two backslashes are required to generate one backslash for the Pattern. Therefore,

```
\\{
```

will properly evaluate to

```
\{
```

Not only this, but the `matches` method checks to see iff the entire string matches, instead of just a subset. Hence, the `^.*` part

Comment: Well this does not give any errors, but it does not give any matches either. And my string surely has a { at the end.

Comment: @user2065207 - Silly question; is it a {, or a }? That is, what is the string you are trying to match?

Comment: I thought of that too. But it is really {.

Comment: For now the string I am trying to match is just "aasdfg{" (just for trying...)

Comment: Hmm. Try `row.matches("^.*\\{$");`, just for fun.

Comment: So what does this expression mean? Something like "anything at the beginng of the line, end a { at the end" ?

Comment: Splendid! And yes, that is what it means. Basically (and I took a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862917/pattern-matcher-vs-pattern-matches), matches will evaluate to see if the ENTIRE string matches, instead of a subset.

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the { character as it is a special char for regex

```
row.matches("\\{$")
```

Answer (score 2):

Did escaping the angle bracket work?

as in `\\{$`

Tried it against

```
hello world{
    whatever{
    hello{dontmatch
    }
}
```

It matched `world{` and `whatever{` but not `hello{dontmatch`

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape the `{` with an `\` but to prevent that the `\{` is read as special character (like `\n` for line-feed) you need to escape also the `\` with an additional `\` resulting to:

```
row.matches("\\{$");
```