# How can I match a Java regex on numbers and slashes (image resolution in a file path)

Tags: java, regex

I'm just trying to create a regex to recognise image resolutions in a file path.

An example input string could be something like "/path/to/file/2048x1556/file.type".

And all i want to be able to match on is the "/2048x1556" bit.

I should not that the numbers of the resolutions can change, but will always be either 3 or 4 characters in length.

I've tried so far using:

```
Pattern.matches("/\\d+x\\d+", myFilePathString)
```

An what feels like about 100 variations on that...  I'm new to regex's so I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance, Matt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method..

`matches` would try to match the string **exactly**.

`find` could match **in between** the string provided you don't use `^`,`$`

See [pattern.matcher() vs pattern.matches()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862917/pattern-matcher-vs-pattern-matches) for more info

---

So,your code would be like

```
boolean isValid=Pattern.compile(yourRegex).matcher(input).find();
```

But if you want to extract:

```
String res="";
Matcher m=Pattern.compile(yourRegex).matcher(input);
if(m.find())res=m.group();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it would be something simple like that!

Answer (score 4):

To determine *if* the filename contains a resolution:

```
if (myFilePathString.matches(".*/\\d{3,4}x\\d{3,4}.*")) {
    // image filename contains a resolution
}
```

To *extract* the resolution in just one line:

```
String resolution = myFilePathString.replaceAll(".*/(\\d{3,4}x\\d{3,4}).*", "$1");
```

Note that the extracted resolution will be blank (not `null`) if there is no resolution in the filename, so you could extract it, then test for blank:

```
String resolution = myFilePathString.replaceAll(".*/(\\d{3,4}x\\d{3,4}).*", "$1");
if (!resolution.isEmpty()) {
    // image filename contains a resolution
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  If i could mark multiple answers as correct I would...  I'll mark this one up still though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Regular expression then

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String regular = "/path/to/file/2048x1556/file.type";

        final String NAME_REGEX = ".*/path/to/file/([^/]+)/";
        System.out.println(runSubRegex(NAME_REGEX, regular));
    }

    private static String runSubRegex(String regex, String tag) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(tag);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```