# Get any Sub-string from a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I would like to get a particular type of substring from a string. 
For example, I want to be able to get the substring `Computer Science` from a string `String text = "I studied Computer Science";`.

Another example is to get the substring `Physics` from a string `String text = "I studied Physics for 5 years at the University of XXXXXXX";`.

Please, how can I achieve this? Thanks

NOTE: It should be flexible for all other types of course(es).

Comment: you can use `substring` method :D

Comment: What sets apart the string you are looking for?

Comment: Are you looking for the third word (easy)? The noun (hard)? Or something entirely different?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your criteria are. You need to specify all cases of what the senteces can look like. Then you migth be able to identify what those have in common. You can then use that for creating a regular expression that matches ypur string.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It could be at any position in the string. E.g "I went to the University of XXXXX to study Computer Science"...Here, "Computer Science" is at the end of the string

Comment: Without more precise requirements, how can we help you? For example, if we can get something that comes after `study`, `studies`, `studied` or `studying` and does not contain a preposition, would that be fine with you?

Comment: You may want to see whether [Java regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-frame.html) may help you. Use your search engine to find one of the many tutorials.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is a natural language processing question that can't be handled by regex alone.

Comment: @WilliamsTobi the example from your comment is already that different from those in your question, that it'll be very hard to find a common pattern. It is also very much out of scope for beeing asked on this site.

Comment: What should come out of, for example, `You can improve your knowledge of the natural world by study and observation.`? `studying his face for a reaction`? `She's studying to be a teacher.`? `I have studied hard.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check if a word that you **previously** know is in a sentence you can use [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)). For example if you gonna recieve *Computer Science* or *Physics* as parameter in your funcion.

```
public boolean checkIfExists(String word) {
   return sentence.contains(word)
}
```

If you don't know what type of word are you gonna search but you know the structure of the sentence: "**I studied XXXX** for ..." you can use [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and then search for the next blank character ang get the word between the index and the next blank character.

If you know all the possible courses that you may search you can build a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) structure and check for all courses if some exists in the sentence.

```
Set<String> courses = {Physics, Computer Science, Maths}
public boolean checkIfExists(String word) {
   return courses.contains(word);
}
```

If you don't know anyone of the previous cases I think the problem is hard and you have to go for [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is related to **Machine Learning**.
You have to process your sentences accordingly..

You can **Tag** the nouns, verb [parts of speeches] in your sentences and break it down and put some logic to find Noun like Physics.

Please find the API through which you can Tag each words, explore more.
**https://opennlp.apache.org/**

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a pattern-matching method. This is a machine learning typical problem and it would be very easy to solve with languages like Python. In Java you can use the Pattern class, you will find this answer helpful: [pattern.matcher() vs pattern.matches()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862917/pattern-matcher-vs-pattern-matches)